# Incrementing numbers in an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I am trying to add functionality to this [visualization](https://codepen.io/gty996/pen/dyoqELW) in order to increment or decrement the nodes from the hidden layers. I added this code:

in order to increase or decrease the number of hidden layers in the hidden layer as I previously mentioned. But I'm not succeeding, therefore, I need some help. Can anybody tell me how is this done and am I on the right track?

```
for (var i = 0; i < vm.hiddenLayersDepths[hiddenLayerLoop]; i++) {
    function minus() {
        vm.hiddenLayersDepths.map(function(val){return --val;});
        //Arrays.fill(vm.hiddenLayersDepths, vm.hiddenLayersDepths[0] - 1);
    }

    function plus() {
        if (vm.hiddenLayersDepths[0] < 5) {
            vm.hiddenLayersDepths.map(function(val){return ++val;});
            //Arrays.fill(vm.hiddenLayersDepths, vm.hiddenLayersDepths[0] + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: I want the + or - to be for each hidden layer independently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To specifically add or remove nodes from ONE layer, each layer will need its + and - buttons. When generating these separate buttons for each index in hiddenLayersCount, I would add a 'dataset' connection from that set of + and - button to the layer it is related to. So in a case with two hidden layers, you would end up with buttons like in your HTML after you add them in with js:

```
<div class"plus-minus-container">
  <input data-id="0" type="button" value="-" class="minus-button">
  <input data-id="0" type="button" value="+" class="plus-button">
</div>

<div class"plus-minus-container">
  <input data-id="1" type="button" value="-" class="minus-button">
  <input data-id="1" type="button" value="+" class="plus-button">
</div>
```

While adding them in with js, you can add on click listeners to each, calling a addNodeToHiddenLayer() or removeNodeFromHiddenLayer() in the vm scope (or wherever you can access the vm.hiddenLayersDepths array).

```
function addNodeToHiddenLayer(event){
  const layerIndex = parseInt(event.target.dataset.id,10);

  if (vm.hiddenLayersDepths[layerIndex] < 5) {
    vm.hiddenLayersDepths[layerIndex] += 1;
  }
}

function removeNodeToHiddenLayer(event){
  const layerIndex = parseInt(event.target.dataset.id,10);
  if (vm.hiddenLayersDepths[layerIndex] > 1) {
    vm.hiddenLayersDepths[layerIndex] -= 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: This looks good, but it isn't working when I try it. Did you try this in the codepen link I posted? Thank you @PedroPessoa

Comment: @luftgekuhltlover, Check this pen out : https://codepen.io/ppessoa/pen/jOPdXwj

I don't really know Angular, so I have only used standard js for this example, but let me know if this is the functionality you are looking for.

I have added " NEW CODE STARTS HERE " comments in the js and html blocks to show you all the changes I have made more explicitly

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly the functionality I was looking for. Also, thanks a lot for the explanatory comments.

Answer (score 1):

**[Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)**

> The `map()` method creates a new array populated with the results of
>   calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

So, reassign the values to `hiddenLayersDepths`.

```
vm.minus = function() {
  vm.hiddenLayersDepths = vm.hiddenLayersDepths.map((i) => i - 1);
  draw();
};

vm.plus = function() {
  vm.hiddenLayersDepths = vm.hiddenLayersDepths.map((i) => i + 1);
  draw();
};
```

**Working Demo**

https://codepen.io/aswinkumar863/pen/ZEGVYBp

Comment: thank you for your answer! This is cool, thank you. But I want to be able to add/remove neurons from each hidden layer separately. In your example the + or - correspond to all of the hidden layers simultaneously. Could it be done, so that I can controll the number of neurons separately for each hidden layer?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this by event binding. Use `ng-click` with your button elements and add corresponding methods inside your controller.

```
<input type="button" value="-" id="moins" ng-click="vm.decrementHiddenLayerCount()">
<input type="button" value="+" id="plus" ng-click="vm.incrementHiddenLayerCount()">
```

Add the corresponding event handlers in your controller. In event handlers, you just need to increment the `ngModel` value. It will keep your view and model in sync. I have added code below where you need to add event handlers.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function( $scope, $interval, $window, $q ) {
    var vm = this;

vm.incrementHiddenLayerCount = function() {
  const hiddenValue = vm.hiddenLayerCountSlider.value;
  if (hiddenValue < vm.hiddenLayerCountSlider.options.ceil) {
    vm.hiddenLayerCountSlider.value += 1;
    vm.hiddenLayersCount = vm.hiddenLayerCountSlider.value;
    draw();
  }
  }

  vm.decrementHiddenLayerCount = function() {
    debugger;
    const hiddenValue = vm.hiddenLayerCountSlider.value;
    if (hiddenValue > vm.hiddenLayerCountSlider.options.floor) {
     vm.hiddenLayerCountSlider.value -= 1;
    vm.hiddenLayersCount = vm.hiddenLayerCountSlider.value;
    draw(); 
    }
  }
```

Please find the working code here: https://codepen.io/jasdeep7991/pen/mdJayKg

Comment: @Prine thank you so much for your answer. But rather than adding new hidden layers I wanted to add nodes in the hidden layers. Anyways I appreciate your help. Thanks so much!